# Could improper crank sensor installation result in stalling?

Tags: electrical, starting, dodge, stall, durango

This is a 2002 Dodge Durango 4.7 L.

It was having issues with stalling and would not start without pumping the pedal.

At this point the IAC, TPS and battery are all new, as well as the (hard-to-install) crank sensor. It fired up & idles like a dream... but stalls.

Comment: Have you read the codes - that may give an indication or are you just replacing things hoping one will cure it?